# Passing a report variable to another expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to pass a report variable to an expression used to populate textbox but it's giving me syntax error. Here's the expression.

```
=Fields!Variables!col1.Value.Value
```

The variable (Variables!col1.Value) should return a fieldname that I want to use to populate a textbox inside a table.

Edit:
Basically I have a multi-value parameter that passes on to a stored procedure that pulls the data based on the parameter value. The first 4-5 columns returned are static while the rest are dynamic and can have unknown number of columns but I do know the max number of columns.

What I'm trying to do is to create a fixed number of columns and then show/hide them based on the parameter. I get the column title via an expression (=Parameters!Course_IDs.Label(0)) and then I want to use this value to create a textbox that will populate the column based on this value Course_IDs.Label(0).

Comment: So you are selecting a variable in your query? Try `Fields!Col1.Value`... Assuming the variable is in col1... If it's a variable in SSRS then use `Parameters!ParameterName.Value`

Comment: yes but neither of your solution works. My variable is a report variable and it contains the name of field/column from a dataset.

Comment: Is it a multi-value parameter?

Comment: yes it is a multi-value parameter

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a multi-valued parameter, you will likely need to join the results:

```
=JOIN(Parameters!ParameterName.Value, ", ")
```

If it is a variable from the dataset you will likely need to use `LOOKUPSET()` to get the values.

Also note that parameter values might be ugly to look at. In that case use the name instead - `Parameters!ParameterName.Label`

Comment: I'm using "=Parameters!Course_IDs.Label(0)" and so on (1,2...) to assign the values to a report variable. Why can't I use this variable in another expression? Is this not supported?

Comment: I think I'm confused at the question. Maybe you can edit the question and provide screenshots or a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I've added some more explanation.